# Laravel - validar arrays de inputs e retornar os valores em caso de erro

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estou criando formulário utilizando o seguinte código:

No arquivo create.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'orcamentos.store']) !!}
{!! Form::text('descricao', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'autofocus']) !!}
{!! Form::text('produto[]', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::text('produto[]', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
// Esse campo produto pode se repetir inúmeras vezes em tela
{!! Form::submit('Salvar', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
```

Perceba que posso ter 'N' input "produto".

No meu controller tenho isso:

```
public function store(OrcamentoRequest $request){...}
```

E na classe OrcamentoRequest quero validar a obrigatoriedade desses campos, alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Dentro de `function rules` eu já fiz algumas tentativas com base nas buscas feita na internet, mas n obtive sucesso.

Abaixo segue algumas tentativas sem sucesso:

TENTATIVA 1:

```
$rules = [
     'descricao' => 'required',
     'produto.*' => 'required',
 ];
```

TENTATIVA 2:

```
foreach($this->request->get('produto') as $key => $val){
  $rules['produto.'.$key] = 'required';
}
```

Achei alguma coisa também na própria documentação. [link aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays) mas nada funcionou.

O erro que esta dando é esse:

```
ErrorException in helpers.php line 531:
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Alguém já passou por isso antes? Ou sabe a resposta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estive a testar e pelo que me parece para estar a fazer dessa maneira é porque está a usar Laravel 5.2, pois os anteriores não tinham validação *built-in* para inputs em array então fiz:

**LARAVEL 5.2:**

HTML:

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    {{$error}}<br>  <!-- imprimir os erros de validação caso haja algum, serão enviados pelo Validator -->
@endforeach

<form action="/product/store" method="POST">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <input type="text" name="descricao" value="{{old('descricao')}}"></input>
    <input type="text" name="products[]" value="{{old('products.0')}}"></input>
    <input type="text" name="products[]" value="{{old('products.1')}}"></input>
    <input type="text" name="products[]" value="{{old('products.2')}}"></input>
    <input type="text" name="products[]" value="{{old('products.3')}}"></input>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Routa:

```
Route::post('/product/store', 'TestsController@product_store');
```

Controlador:

```
use Validator;
...

public function product_store(Request $request) {

    $inputs = $request->except('_token'); // valores de todos os inputs excepto o do csfr token
    // $inputs = Array ( [descricao] => mobilidade [products] => Array ( [0] => carro [1] => mota [2] => camiao [3] => barco) )

    $rules = array(
        'descricao' => 'required', // mesmo nome dos nossos inputs, name="descricao"
        'products.*' => 'required' // mesmo nome dos nossos inputs, name="products"
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($inputs, $rules);
    if($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator); // voltar para trás e enviar os erros, regras ($rules), que não foram respeitadas
    }
    // Esta tudo bem, fazer outras coisas
}
```

E funcionou.

**LARAVEL 5.1:**

Aqui tive de fazer uma abordagem um pouco diferente visto que não parece ter validação para arrays por default:

A unica coisa que mudei foi no controlador, ficando assim:

```
public function product_store(Request $request) {

    $inputs = $request->except('_token');
    // $inputs = Array ( [descricao] => mobilidade [products] => Array ( [0] => carro [1] => mota [2] => camiao [3] => barco) )

    $products = array(
        'descricao' => $inputs['descricao'], // valor da descricao introduzido
    );

    $rules = array(
        'descricao' => 'required', // mesma key que demos nos $products
    );

    foreach ($inputs['products'] as $key => $value) {
        $products['product_' .$key] = $value;
        $rules['product_' .$key] = 'required';
    }

    $validator = Validator::make($products, $rules);
    if($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator); // voltar para trás e enviar os erros, regras ($rules), que não foram respeitadas
    }
    // Esta tudo bem, fazer outras coisas
}
```

**Lembre-se sempre que as keys das regras, nosso `$rules`, têm de ser as mesmas keys do array que vamos validar, neste ultimo caso do `$products`**.

Comment: Obrigado pelas explicações... Usei o exemplo do 5.2 mas ele não sabe preencher os campos no momento que mostra a mensagem de erro. Isso aconteceu com você também?

Comment: Eu vou editar, para que isso aconteça, esteja atento

Comment: Obrigado, isso até funcionou, mas to achando que o código ta ficando um pouco 'estranho' de mais... mudando um pouco meu projeto e deixando os inputs assim produto[1], produto[2]...  e colocando dentro das rules assim 'produto.*' => required . Dai o Laravel já sabe validar e preencher os dados de volta no momento de remontar a tela, acho que vou para esse lado. Eu sinceramente não queria mexer nas minhas views, mas dentro da devida circunstancia acho que é a melhor opção. Obrigado, sua ajuda foi muito importante.

Comment: Terá de pelo menos no html acresentar nos values dos inputs aquilo que eu tenho em cima, products.0, lembre-se que não é products[0] é como eu tenho ali. E acrescentar `withInput()` no redirect quando há erros

Comment: Só não gostei muito dessa parte aqui: {{old('products.1')}} , isso ter que ficar fixo nos inputs da view acho meio "gambiarra", pois como ficar a view de edição dos dados???, dai essa tua solução não resolveria eu acho. Por isso vou utilizar os inputs numerados pois desse modo o Laravel já sabe trabalhar.

Comment: Eu também confesso que acho o mesmo. Mas não conheço nada melhor para isso usando o Laravel

Comment: Qual o lugar mais aconselhado de eu colocar as conclusões que chegamos a partir desses discursos para a próxima pessoa não precisar ler todos os comentários?

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta de acordo com as coisas que ficou esclarecido e que a solução cobre. Já editei o titulo, acho que esse é mais adequado à nossa dicussão

Comment: Também pode guardar em Sessão os valores dos inputs, ex: `value={{Session:get('products')[0]}}`...

Comment: @AndersonSouza percebi a sua duvida quanto ao que fazer no editar. Fácil, no `value` ponha `value="{{$obj_a_editar->product0 or old('products.0')}}"`, que é o equivalente a `value="@if(isset($obj_a_editar)){{$obj_a_editar->product0}}@else{{old('product.0')}}@endif"`

Comment: Pois é, mas acho que vai ficar coisa de mais no código... mas obrigado por tentar ajudar. Mas eu vou trocar o nome dos inputs nas views mesmo, vou deixar assim produto[1], produto[2] ...  vai me dar mais trabalho agora, mas o código vai ficar mais limpo.